# How can i solve this artifact in CSM

Tags: shadow-mapping

I have the next issue when a object is suspended in the air far enough of the ground.

[image]

How the algorithm works:

- It checks if the coordinates in the light view matrix of this cascade are inside the the actual cascade's view ([0,1] interval).
- If it is inside, it checks the depth to see if it is in shadow and finish.
- If it is not, it checks the next cascade.

The coordinate that it is checking is actually inside this shadow cascade, but the cube lands just partially in this shadow cascade, and for this reason the surface is cut and you can see the floor that is at the other side of the cube, which is the floor that is checking to draw or not the shadow, producing this artifact.

Is it any way to solve it? I tried checking if the next cascade has lower depth but it cause other problems and artifacts that are even worse because of the glur effect and the lower precision of the next cascade.

It just happen with distant flying objects or high objects, anything else it works great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your near clip could be set wrong.

Alos the thing with shadows is that sometimes you cant see the object but it casts shadows so u need to handle the culling different.

So for normal rendering you want just whats in front of the camera but for shadows u need some of the objects that are behind the camera.

I use the lightview frustum from each cascade to cull the objects.

But after looking at you screen shot I really think its your near clip for the shadow camera and the shadow looks funny to me.... like its distorted.

[image]

I tried VSM for a while but I didn't like how they looked so I went back to PCF:

```
// Calculates the shadow term using PCF soft-shadowing
// sqrtSample is the filter size. I.e. 2 for 2x2 PCF, 3 for 3x3 PCF, etc.
float2 CalculateShadowTermSoftPCF(float2 texCoord, float ourdepth, Texture2D ShadowMap,uint sqrtSamples)
{
float shadowTerm = 0.0f;

float radius = (sqrtSamples - 1.0f) / 2;

float Depth = ShadowMap.Load(int3(texCoord, 0)).r;
for (float y = -radius; y <= radius; y++)
{
    for (float x = -radius; x <= radius; x++)
    {
        float2 offset = float2(x, y) / ShadowMapSize;
        float sampleDepth = ShadowMap.SampleCmpLevelZero(samShadow, texCoord + offset, ourdepth).r;


        // Edge tap smoothing
        float xWeight = 1;
        float yWeight = 1;

        if (x == -radius)
            xWeight = 1 - frac(texCoord.x * ShadowMapSize.x);
        else if (x == radius)
            xWeight = frac(texCoord.x * ShadowMapSize.x);

        if (y == -radius)
            yWeight = 1 - frac(texCoord.y * ShadowMapSize.y);
        else if (y == radius)
            yWeight = frac(texCoord.y * ShadowMapSize.y);

        shadowTerm += sampleDepth * xWeight * yWeight;

    }
}

shadowTerm /= ((sqrtSamples - 1.1) * (sqrtSamples - 1.1));
return float2(shadowTerm, Depth);
}
```

Random disk filter:

```
 float2 poissonDisk[24] =
 {
 float2(-0.4448907f, 0.7713736f),
 float2(-0.4675094f, 0.4431239f),
 float2(-0.1220913f, 0.5835819f),
 float2(-0.8736015f, 0.3635427f),
 float2(-0.2091058f, 0.0196037f),
 float2(-0.7448996f, 0.6206658f),
 float2(0.2112615f, 0.1990242f),
 float2(-0.572591f, -0.1135838f),
 float2(0.2162377f, 0.7406282f),
 float2(0.4967479f, 0.5918304f),
 float2(0.4943127f, -0.0736846f),
 float2(-0.461087f, -0.393838f),
 float2(-0.8604655f, -0.04897872f),
 float2(-0.09501296f, -0.808184f),
 float2(0.8711416f, 0.248008f),
 float2(0.07829998f, -0.1680121f),
 float2(0.4522456f, -0.5761201f),
 float2(0.6582519f, -0.3458804f),
 float2(-0.1601302f, -0.4334383f),
 float2(-0.3873517f, -0.7103282f),
 float2(0.2616926f, -0.8700755f),
 float2(-0.7656811f, -0.6018973f),
 float2(0.9460136f, -0.1249114f),
 float2(0.5343407f, 0.2145455f)
};

float poissonDiskFilter24Samples(float2 texCoord, float ourdepth, Texture2D ShadowMap)
{
// Get the current depth stored in the shadow map
float4 samples[24];

float shadow = 0;

float2 pixelSize = ShadowMapPixelSize * spread;

[unroll]
for (int i = 0; i < totalSamples; i++)
{
    samples[i] = ShadowMap.SampleCmp(samShadow, texCoord + poissonDisk[i] * pixelSize,ourdepth).r;
    shadow += samples[i];
}

// shadow /= totalSamples  * totalSamples ;
shadow /= ((totalSamples - 1.1) * (totalSamples - 1.1));

return totalSamples * shadow;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes it is because the VSM i think(the distorsed shadow). About the clipped shadow, yes, it is because the object is behind the camera of the first shadow cascade, i know it. The thing is that if i increase the far distance of the camera it will reduce the shadow quality, and that is the main point of using CSM, to have different shadow maps with closer cameras to have better shadows. I can fix that increasing the lenght of the orthographic projection but the cost is the shadow quality.

Comment: can you use a boundingbox to include objects behind the camera. I use CMS too with 3 splits. Ill post a screen shot of my shadow buffer for you. Ill also post some code so u can see how I build my split views

Comment: I thought that the length of the orthographic projection actually had a impact on the quality of the shadows, but i tried it and actually it doesn´t, ill approve your answer, thank you very much :)

Comment: Yes i use a bounding box which contains all the frustum calculed in light view and that things. The point was that i thought that the Z component of the orthographic projection had a negative impact on quality but it doesn´t look like it. I'm using now the far distance view as the Z length of each cascade and the quality of the shadows are the just like before. (the different between cascades are the width and the height of course)

Comment: Well happy I could help :)

Comment: Looking at your shadow map i see that you just use your R color component. That means that you don't use VSM or ESM, what do you use as shadow softer? I know that are many different ones, that i also used at past, but VSM is probably the most common one. It is just for curiosity.

Comment: updated answer for what u asked

Comment: It depends also on the style of the game. For a retro game PCF looks better because it is like more pixeled. I personally prefer to use VSM, they look more realistic to me, but how i said, if i would want to make a retro game, i would use PCF. Anyways i saw PCFs using random texel rotations which look pretty nice(i have never tried to implement it). Anyways, thank you for your reply, i am new in 3D engines development(i used to work in 2D) and some stuffs are new for me.

Comment: I'm not making a retro game, ill update my answer with a screen shot of the shadows in game

Comment: Your shadows look great! Yes i read about the rotation disk for PCFs, ill try to implement them to see how they work. I read about them but the results showed weren't that great than yours. If you can arch that softness ill try them too see what performance i can reach with them.